# Alternate idiom for “Let them eat cake”

Tags: idiom-requests

Unfortunately that phrase habitually comes to mind when I want to be *chidingly sarcastic* towards someone who is out of touch with the reality of a subject, as it's not the right idiom.

This is an obscure reference – too obscure I think for general use, but a good example – the humorous quip from the movie *Heathers (1988)*, where the reply to a long idealistic diatribe is: *“Call me when the shuttle lands.”* (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bZx9DhBlB0w)

I don't think that even makes sense logically, but his position is well understood nevertheless.

Other examples:

- *“I think war should just be outlawed.”* [said in self-righteous definitive tone by a 17 year old] - - A general idiomatic sardonic reply: ____________________.
- *“I don't understand why there are poor people; they should all just get jobs.”* [said by annoyed wealthy Beverly Hills woman] - - Reply: ____________________.
- etc.

Pithy, sublime, snarky, or what have you.  Preferably something with some teeth that's instantly understood to be sarcastic, or ironic.  I'm thinking of a movie set-piece where your favorite decidedly snobbish upper class British character has a deadly quip for just such an occasion.

Comment: Here in Minnesota we say "Let them eat lutefisk!"

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a sarcastic retort that means "Get your head out of the clouds." Is that the right shade of meaning?

Comment: @Nonnal - I'm looking for exactly _“Let them eat cake”_, in the sense of a poignant idiomatic retort for pointing out (mocking them) that someone is completely out of touch with reality, except that idiom doesn't work in the more general examples given, and that have nothing to do with supplying a population food.  Thank you for replying and suggestion.

Comment: Larry, the way *you* are using "Let them eat cake" is not at all common (possibly unique to you) and probably goes entirely over the head of the listener. As you say in your question, it's the wrong idiom. So what you are looking for is not at all *exactly* "Let them eat cake".

Comment: He's using exactly the right "Let them eat cake" isn't he? The entire point of the phrase is that someone is so out of touch with reality/regular people that their response to "There's a shortage of bread" is to say "Well then, they should eat cake instead", as if that's a sensible solution. In modern parlance, "Let them eat cake" is often used as a retort when someone makes a completely impractical suggestion which is out of touch with reality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **[is that so?](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Is+that+so)**

> That is what you say, but I do not believe you. (No rising question intonation. Slightly rude.) Mary: You are making a mess of this. Alice: Is that so?

Alternatively, **[is that a fact?](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/is+that+a+fact%3f)**

> Also, is that so? Phrases indicating that one is following what another person is saying. These expressions, which require no reply, can be used either straightforwardly, as in You mean you've flown to Paris three times just this month? Is that a fact? **or sarcastically, expressing disbelief or contempt, as in Just wait, I'll be promoted over you before the year is out.-Oh yeah, is that so?** [Late 1800s]

(emphasis mine)

Another possibility is **[good luck with that](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/good-luck-with-that.)**:

> statement used to express doubt in the future success of someone's plan.

Comment: Good suggestions.  The first is perfectly snarky, but perhaps a bit too subtle for most of my fellow Americans.  For example, I wouldn't know what was really meant unless Bill Nighy sneered it at me.  The last one reminded me of another - _**"When pigs fly"**._

Answer (score 1):

Consider,

***Don't hold your breath***

> *Fig.* Do not stop breathing waiting for something to happen that won't
> happen. (Meaning that it will take longer for it to happen than you
> can possibly hold your breath.) Sally: *Someone said that gasoline
> prices would go down*. Bob: *Oh, yeah? Don't hold your breath*.
> [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal
> Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Don%27t+hold+your+breath)

***We should be so lucky!***

> You should be so lucky!
>
> (*informal*) Something that you say in order to tell someone that what they want is not likely to happen [Cambridge Idioms Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Don%27t+you+should+be+so+lucky)

***In your dreams!***

> (*humorous*) Something that you say to someone who has just told you about something they are hoping for, in order to show that you do not believe it will happen [Cambridge Idioms Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Don%27t+in+your+dreams)

Comment: None of these have the same meaning as "Let them eat cake"

Comment: @Elian - I appreciate the suggestions.  The last one reminds me of when I was a kid in the late 70s, we would say _**“Look boss: Ze plane!  Ze plane!”**_, in a kind of clunky American association-slang, where the person hearing that would know the actual retort is _**“Welcome to Fantasy Island.”**_ - mocking the person who just made an outrageous claim.  (Obviously I've watched too much TV in my life.)

Answer (score 1):

How about: "Yeah, right! That'll happen..."
(...works with both your examples.)